# Excel INDIRECT filename in a cell

Tags: excel

The setup:

```
G:\Mike\Wip Summary.xlsx
```

Has a table on it's only sheet which in the Title column (B) wants to look to Job No (A) and use the value in that row to build a reference to an external workbook in a different directory.

For example, in B5 I want to display the name of the job, which is always stored in cell D1 of a workbook, located here:

```
G:\Mike\WIP Sheets\[name of file is in Column A of the WIP Summary.xlsx file].xlsx
```

So, in cell A5, for example, is the value of R1711. I want Excel, to build a reference to the D1 on the Summary tab/sheet of workbook

```
G:\Mike\WIP Sheets\R1711.xlsx
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `INDIRECT` simply NEVER works with closed files... sorry. as it looks to me, you would need vba to do the job...

Comment: The file is open, I know that it doesn't work otherwise. I didn't mention that it was closed. :)

Comment: if the workbook is open, you do not need any path (you cannot open 2 workbooks at the same time with the same name... even if they are at different locations). So if B5 looks at A5 to get the D1 you formula should look like this: `=INDIRECT("["&A5&".xlsx]Summary!$D$1",TRUE)`... just change the ranges to fit your needs (and sheet names... if they not already do)